# Header files confliction definitions

Tags: compiler-errors, header

I have "vendaStruct.h" where I define a struct and its API.

Then, I have "fileToMemory.h" where I have definitions that use that struct.

Well, when compiling it says the struct doesnt exist in the fileToMemory functions, but if I include "vendaStruct.h" in "fileToMemory.h" it now has confliting types.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have made a misstake in the use of the struct. It is not possible to say for sure what misstake you have made without seeing the code that declares the struct and the code that is using it.